# Show multiple images in same window with Python OpenCV?

Tags: opencv, python-2.7

I want to display original image left side and grayscale image on right side. Below is my code, I create grayscale image and create window, but I couldn't put grayscale image to right side. How can I do this?

```
import cv
import time
from PIL import Image
import sys

filePath = raw_input("file path: ")
filename = filePath

img = cv.LoadImage(filename)
imgGrayScale = cv.LoadImage(filename, cv.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE) # create grayscale image

imgW = img.width
imgH = img.height

cv.NamedWindow("title", cv.CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)
cv.ShowImage("title", img )
cv.ResizeWindow("title", imgW * 2, imgH)

cv.WaitKey()
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11067962/is-it-possible-to-have-black-and-white-and-color-image-on-same-window-by-using-o/11069276

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14579541/how-do-i-concatenate-two-matrices-in-python-opencv/14584537

Comment: As @Abid wrote, solution is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11067962/is-it-possible-to-have-black-and-white-and-color-image-on-same-window-by-using-o/11069276

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, one window, one image. So create a new image with imgW*2 and copy the contents of the grayscale image at the region starting from (originalimage.width,0). The ROI capabilities may be helpful to you.

Comment: I found this one: [DisplayManyImages](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/DisplayManyImages) I couldn't for python

Comment: aww, that's damn old. but basically the same idea as the answer above, make an image with space for both, and copy each into a ROI

Answer (score 9):

First concatenate the images either horizontally (across columns) or vertically (across rows) and then display it as a single image.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from skimage.data import astronaut
import scipy.misc as misc
img=cv2.cvtColor(astronaut(),cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
numpy_horizontal_concat = np.concatenate((img, img), axis=1)
cv2.imshow('Numpy Horizontal Concat', numpy_horizontal_concat)
```

[image]

Comment: This was super helpful and simple, thank you!

Comment: Well, you did it and with importing only **4** packages!   
(It can be done wiith only Numpy and cv2). 
That's what I call **very ineffective** programming. (I should downvoted this answer but I didn't.)