# How to show multiple video frames in a single window using python opencv2

Tags: python, opencv, video

I wants to show multiple video frames in a single window. 
When I google for this, I have found a similar site : 
 http://devblog.michalski.im/2012/05/18/combine-multiple-video-frames-into-one-using-opencv/. 
But I need the code in python opencv2. I hope it is possible in python opencv2. Can anyone help me by giving a sample code or idea ...? Thanks...

Comment: try numpy's hstack function..it is used to stack images side by side in the same window

Comment: Also see the answer [here](http://answers.opencv.org/question/23048/display-many-images-in-single-window-in-opencv/#23054)

Comment: Thank you. I am trying this one ... I hope this will help me.

Comment: @Thamizh : Did you manage to find the pythonic version of this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I followed the below link and got the correct answer for videos. 
Thanks to "Vipul Sharma" & "Haris" for their help to get the answer. 
And Thanks to "Abid Rahman K" for his answer. 
 
Link : [Is it possible to have black and white and color image on same window by using opencv?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11067962/is-it-possible-to-have-black-and-white-and-color-image-on-same-window-by-using-o/11069276) 
Thank you friends.