# Why is the image being used an image from a previous process?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

Quite simply, I'm learning how to edit photos with `openCV`/`numpy`.

My question is why is the *second* function using the image created by the first?

I run two functions - one to color columns in black and white, and a second that colors rows in black and white.

First function runs fine, but the second one uses the image created in the first, so I get rows *and columns* in black and white.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img_source = "brad.jpg"

def read_image(image_source):
    #global img, width, height
    img = cv2.imread(image_source, 1)
    height, width = img.shape[:2]
    print("Image size: x ", width, " y ", height)
    return img, width, height

def black_and_white_cols(image_source):
    width_adjustment = 100
    total_cols = round(width / width_adjustment,0)
    edited_image = image_source
    bw_image = cv2.imread(img_source, 0)
    # The next line is to convert to the right interface
    # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11067962/is-it-possible-to-have-black-and-white-and-color-image-on-same-window-by-using-o
    bw_image_b = cv2.cvtColor(bw_image,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

    for x in range(1, int(total_cols), 2):
        top_row = 0
        bottom_row = height
        left_col = x*width_adjustment
        right_col = (x * width_adjustment) + width_adjustment
        bw_part = bw_image_b[top_row:bottom_row, left_col:right_col]
        edited_image[top_row:bottom_row, left_col:right_col] = bw_part
    show_image(edited_image)

def black_and_white_cols(image_source):
    width_adjustment = 100
    total_cols = round(width / width_adjustment,0)
    edited_image = image_source
    bw_image = cv2.imread(img_source, 0)
    # The next line is to convert to the right interface
    # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11067962/is-it-possible-to-have-black-and-white-and-color-image-on-same-window-by-using-o
    bw_image_b = cv2.cvtColor(bw_image,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

    for x in range(1, int(total_cols), 2):
        top_row = 0
        bottom_row = height
        left_col = x*width_adjustment
        right_col = (x * width_adjustment) + width_adjustment
        bw_part = bw_image_b[top_row:bottom_row, left_col:right_col]
        edited_image[top_row:bottom_row, left_col:right_col] = bw_part
    show_image(edited_image)
    return edited_image

def black_and_white_rows(image_source):
    width_adjustment = 100
    edited_image = image_source
    total_rows = round(height / width_adjustment,0)
    bw_image = cv2.imread(img_source, 0)
    bw_image_b = cv2.cvtColor(bw_image,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

    for x in range(1, int(total_rows), 2):
        top_row = x * width_adjustment
        bottom_row = (x * width_adjustment) + width_adjustment
        left_col = 0
        right_col = width
        bw_part = bw_image_b[top_row:bottom_row, left_col:right_col]
        edited_image[top_row:bottom_row, left_col:right_col] = bw_part

    show_image(edited_image)

def show_image(image_source):
    cv2.imshow('This is your image', image_source)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    img, width, height = read_image(img_source)
    new_image = black_and_white_cols(img)
    new_image_2 = black_and_white_rows(img)
```

This is the image after `new_image = black_and_white_cols(img)` runs.

[image]

and here's after `new_image_2 = ...` runs.

[image]

Why does the second image keep the black and white columns? I'm calling it using the very original `img_source` image, via `read_image`.  Why is it using the column edited image?

Comment: Because they share the same reference.

Comment: Maybe you need `from copy import deepcopy`?

Comment: `img_source` and `edited_image` are the same image, just as you defined them to be with the statement `edited_image = image_source`. Therefore, when you change `edited_image`, you are also changing `image_source`.

Comment: @kindall - So, when I edit an image (like I do with `edited_image[top_row:bottom_row, left_col:right_col] = bw_part`), that's actually editing the "true image", even if I don't save it or `return edited_image`?

Comment: Yes, exactly. They are two names for the same object.

Comment: @kindall - Oh, okay! That answers it, so simple! I just figured that by using `edited_image = image_source`, I was effectively using a copy to make the b&w images, not actually editing `img`, and also since I didn't `return edited_image`, it would only remain b&w while being called in that specific function (kind of like a local variable).

Comment: If solution is working, please convert the comment it to an answer so that @BruceWayne can accept it and close this as "solved".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in the comments, when you do `edited_image = image_source`, you only copy the pointer to the image array, not cloning the array itself. You can do

`edited_image = image_source.copy()`

which copies `image_source` to `edited_image`.